# how to get alternate route in google map using android studio?

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio

How to get driving alternate route in google map using android studio? When you enter your current location and your destination then it will show 3 different alternate routes just like the google map.My problem is how i will get those 3 routes and when you click one of them it will show the direction from current to destination with poylines.

Comment: Share your workaround/code.

Comment: my code shows only one route. yet.